# Print Histogram in Java

Tags: java, histogram

I'm trying to print out a histogram using the values in my TreeMap. I'm using the smallest number as base, and the ratio of the numbers vs the base determines the height of the histogram bars. The following is my code: It will print out horizontal bars indicated by the asterisk "*". The base (value of 1) will have two stars. However, the problem is all the other bars also have two stars, which looks no different than the base.

```
private static void printHistogram(TreeMap<String, Integer> mapA)
    {
        int baseVal = mapA.firstEntry().getValue();
        String baseKey = mapA.firstKey();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : mapA.entrySet())
        {
            int times = e.getValue() / baseVal;
            System.out.print(e.getKey() + "\t \|");
            for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("**");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

This is the histogram printout:

```
21  |**
22  |**
23  |**
24  |**
25  |**
26  |**
27  |**
28  |**
29  |**
30  |**
31  |**
32  |**
33  |**
```

The following is the numbers in my TreeMap (before sorting):

```
99255
98321
98860
95365
85412
86105
84972
88132
80223
76273
74056
74077
52523
```

The ratios vs the base number 52523 are less than 2. I am wondering how to magnify the differences visually? Because I am printing out the histogram in terminal, I cannot use a graphical histogram library unless it can save the image as file.

Comment: I found lowering the base val to 700-900 makes the histogram a lot nicer - to magnify the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend this: 
You have `min_v` and `max_v` values, then choose how many stars you would like to have for `max_v` value (say, to fit half the screen) - denote as N, and also M < N stars for `min_v` value (could be 0, for example)
Then, number of stars for each value is :

**M + (N - M) * (e.getValue() - min_v) / (max_v - min_v)**

Comment: Welcome. Btw, the values in `treeMap` are not sorted, only the keys are.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a star for each deviation of `baseValue`, make it e.g. a star for each tenth deviation from the base value:

```
int times = e.getValue() / 0.1*baseVal;
```

The `0.1` can then be turned into a parameter depending on the distribution of the values. If it can get very large, increase it (0.2 would create a star for each 20% baseValue deviation). For very narrow numbers, make it even smaller.

Personally, I would make the histogram according to the difference between max and min, not depending on the baseValue itself.

- Determine how many stars you want to show max (depends on the terminal size)
- calculate difference `diff = max - min`
- for each star, you need `step = diff/stars` increase in value for it to show up.

Comment: I've added an idea for improvement as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void histogram() {
        int [] n = {19, 3, 15, 7, 11, 9, 13, 5, 17, 1};
        System.out.println("Element"+"\t"+"Value"+"\t"+"Histogram");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i =0;i<n.length; i++){
          System.out.print(i+"\t"+n[i]+"\t");
            for(int j=0;j<n[i]; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
        }System.out.println();
                   
      }
    }
```